# Cannot open terminal after resizing VirtualBox disk drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted

I followed the steps to resize a VirualBox disk drive:

http://www.jochenhebbrecht.be/site/2016-07-11/windows/resizing-disk-drive-in-ubuntu-guest-system-running-a-virtual-box-windows-host-syt

As said in the above source before resizing the disk I released but the source forgot to mentioned that the disk then has to be mounted back, which I did.

After resizing I logged in and should do the partition as mentioned in the above source but when searching for a terminal using the "Search your computer" button

[image]

I get the following error:

"Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search"

Likewise  <kbd>Ctrl Alt + T</kbd>  also did not work.

What has gone wrong and how to fix?

Comment: Have you try to install an other terminal (like Terminator for example) with Ubuntu Software Manager or by downloading on the web (and installing the package with magic)?

Comment: Please tell us with what commands and where you "searched for a terminal". Can you open a terminal with Ctrl + Alt + T ?